# Battery only charging when shutting down by holding the power button or in suspended mode

Tags: power-management, battery

I have an ASUS-UX305F zenbook. Everything was working fine with Windows 10 until I recently installed KDE 16.10 (I removed Windows 10, so it is not a dual boot) and now I can't properly charge my laptop:

```
mat@matlaptop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety
```

The *only* way I can charge it is:

- by holding the power button until my laptop shutdowns (a regular
  shutdown doesn't help)
- when the laptop is in suspended mode (e.g. by running `systemctl suspend`)

If my laptop is active and I plug the charger in the led that indicates if the battery is charging starts to blink a few times than it turns off. This is what the power command returns (while the charger is plugged):

```
mat@matlaptop:~$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Son 12 Mär 2017 21:03:17 CET (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              6,463 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         38,771 Wh
    energy-full-design:  45,03 Wh
    energy-rate:         6,669 W
    voltage:             11,4 V
    time to empty:       58,1 minutes
    percentage:          16%
    capacity:            86,1004%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-low-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1489348992  16,000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1489348997  6,669   discharging
    1489348993  6,270   discharging
    1489348992  6,555   discharging
    1489348928  8,458   discharging
```

Is there any way to fix this?

**EDIT:**

The baterry also charges when the laptop is in suspend mode (`systemctl suspend`)!

As requested by @ElderGeek, here is the [output](http://pastebin.com/raw/5MQ7JPgf) from the `grep ACPI /var/log/syslog` command.

Comment: Please try another ac adapter with same the connector type and check the output settings. I believe your installation of Ubuntu 16.10 has got nothing to do with charging.

Comment: Very interesting. I've never heard of this kind of problem... or thought this might even be possible.

Comment: Very odd, as @MadMike pointed out. Have you considered using a non-ubuntu kernel, perhaps one of the newer mainline kernels? The only feasible explanation I can think of is that there is a conflict with the power management from the kernel, which perhaps actively stops charging (if such a thing is possible)? Do you still have windows as a dual-boot and, if so, does the charging still work under Windows? That'd be an easy way to tell if it's a very-conveniently-timed hardware issue.

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `grep ACPI /var/log/syslog` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @Aargonian I don't have dual-boot any more. The problem started when I installed Ubuntu 16.10 as a dual-boot, but it got worse when I uninstalled windows and installed KDE. I really don't understand what is going on. I'll try to charge my laptop with a new charger to discard that problem.

Comment: @ElderGeek The output has 687 lines so I cannot paste it all, do you need any information in particular?

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of lines! Perhaps you could provide a link to a [pastie](http://pastebin.com/) for us.

Comment: @ElderGeek done!

Comment: This could be a kernel bug (Please add the output of `uname -a`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55703/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-mat).

Comment: you might want to check [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195607) Hope this helps!! Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charger was broken. I just bought a new one and everything works fine now. Thank you.